# MySQL - How to structure DB for millions rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of trades with 2.5M rows.

I try to run this **query**:

```
 SELECT id, price FROM trade
 order by price DESC
 limit 30
```

this query takes about 3 seconds.

I tried to create an index for the columns that I order by but the order is generic and can be on other columns (quantity, date, etc...).

What can I do to improve the execution time of order 2.5M rows without indexes?

Comment: Possible solutions: #1 - do nothing, wait for 3 second; #2 - create index by each column which can be used in ORDER BY; #3 - create additional table (actualized by triggers) which stores top 30 rows ids for each column which can be used in ORDER BY.

Comment: Or run your DB on a better specified platform

Comment: Title asks how can I structure database question says without indexes - the 2 are mutually incompatible.

Comment: @Akina Can you explain the third solution please

Comment: How many columns have you got ?  Are all your queries without a where clause ?  If so, then a sql engine is not the right solution.  I would suggest that you filter the rows and have indexes on the columns you are using for filtering.  It is ludicrous to assume that some one will want to scroll through 2.5M records.  At 100 rows a page, if the user scrolls every 2 seconds, it will take about 13 hours.